# Import picture from internet

Tags: python, image

I am working on a project that will take an image[s] from an online webcam such as
[this](https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=123456789) and then be able to apply some edge detection and motion detection. I have the edge and motion detection running if I import an image already saved on the pi.

I can import an image from the terminal with:

```
wget -nd /pi/Documents/ -A jpg https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=1234556789
```

I don't know how to put that in a python script though.

Comment: This is not a Pi specific question and would be better on our sister site stackoverrflow.com. However, I would suggest at least mentioning what language you are using (Python, bash, Perl etc.).

Comment: Sorry about that, python

Answer (score 1):

From in python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["wget", "-nd","/pi/Documents/","-A","https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=1234556789"])
```

Or with bash

Bash scripts only require a header line and then can be a list of the same commands you type in the terminal. There are many other things you can do as far as handling errors, output, etc... but to get you started

Create a file myscript.sh (doesnt matter the name)
add these two lines

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -nd /pi/Documents/ -A jpg https://www.skikelly.com/sf/liveview/?rand=1234556789
```

make it executable

```
$chmod +x myscript.sh
```

run it

```
$./myscript.sh
```